I am using mediapipe tflite model and infrence speed is too long around (900ms)
When running the same model on native android it is giving aroung 90 ms but when runinng the model using tflite_flutter library it is taking around 900ms , I have really tried many things but cant solve this issue.
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:camera_app/utils/image_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as image_lib;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import '../core/constants.dart';

class MediaPipeProcessor {
  late List<Object> inputs;
  List<dynamic> identity =   Float32List(1*195).reshape([1,195]);
  List<dynamic> identity_1 = Float32List(1*1).reshape([1 , 1]);
  List<dynamic> identity_2 = Float32List(1*256*256*1).reshape([1,256,256,1]);
  List<dynamic> identity_3 = Float32List(1*64*64*39).reshape([1,64,64,39]);
  List<dynamic> identity_4 = Float32List(1*117).reshape([1,117]);
  late int imageWidth;
  late int imageHeight;
  late Interpreter _interpreter ;
  late List<dynamic> inputBuffer ;

  MediaPipeProcessor({Interpreter? interpreter}) {
    loadModel(interpreter: interpreter);
  }
  Interpreter get interpreter => _interpreter;

  loadModel({Interpreter? interpreter}) async {
    try {
      InterpreterOptions? interpreterOptions;
      //GPU DELEGATE CODE
      /* GPU delegate code
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        final gpuDelegateV2 = GpuDelegateV2(
          options: GpuDelegateOptionsV2(
            isPrecisionLossAllowed: false,
            inferencePreference: TfLiteGpuInferenceUsage.fastSingleAnswer,
            inferencePriority1: TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.minLatency,
            inferencePriority2: TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
            inferencePriority3: TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
          ),
        );

        interpreterOptions = InterpreterOptions()
          ..addDelegate(gpuDelegateV2)
          ..threads = 4;
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        final gpuDelegateMetal = GpuDelegate(
          options: GpuDelegateOptions(
            allowPrecisionLoss: true,
            waitType: TFLGpuDelegateWaitType.active,
          ),
        );
        interpreterOptions = InterpreterOptions()
          ..addDelegate(gpuDelegateMetal)
          ..threads = 4;
      }
      */
      _interpreter = interpreter ??
          await Interpreter.fromAsset(
            "assets/mediapipe.tflite",
            options: InterpreterOptions()..threads = 4,
          );
      
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error while creating interpreter: $e");
    }
    //TESTING CODE
    /* Testing code
    var outputTensors = interpreter.getOutputTensors();
    var inputTensors = interpreter.getInputTensors();
    List<List<int>> _outputShapes = [];

    outputTensors.forEach((tensor) {
      print("Output Tensor: " + tensor.toString());
      _outputShapes.add(tensor.shape);
    });
    inputTensors.forEach((tensor) {
      print("Input Tensor: " + tensor.toString());
    });

    print("------------------[A}========================\n" +
        _outputShapes.toString());
    */
  }

  int frameNo = 0;

  runModel() async {
    Map<int, Object> outputs = {0 : identity , 1 : identity_1 , 2 : identity_2 , 3 : identity_3 , 4 : identity_4};
    final startTime = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    _interpreter.runForMultipleInputs(inputs, outputs);
    final endTime = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
    final difference = endTime - startTime;
    print("Interpreter Execution Time : $difference ");
    //IT IS SHOWING AROUND 900MS 
    // print(" Output list prepared Mediapipe $identity");
  }

  Map<String, List<dynamic>> parseData() {
    List result = [];
    List identityT = identity.reshape([39 , 5]);
    for (var i = 0; i < 39 ; i ++) {
      double x = identityT[i][0] / 256 * imageWidth; // x-coordinate
      double y = identityT[i][1] / 256 * imageHeight; // y-coordinate
      // Actual Cordinates
      result.add([x,y]);
    }
    print("$result");
    return {
      'resultsCoordinates': result,
      'frames' : inputBuffer
    };
  }


  Future<void> performOperations(CameraImage cameraImage) async {
    image_lib.Image? convertedImage;
    convertedImage = ImageUtils.convertCameraImage(cameraImage);
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      // convertedImage = image_lib.flipHorizontal(convertedImage!);
    }
    // Manual image preprocessing
    imageWidth = convertedImage!.width;
    imageHeight = convertedImage.height;

    image_lib.Image resizedImage = image_lib.copyResize(
        convertedImage,
        width: 256,
        height: 256
    );

    // final int pixelCount = resizedImage.width * resizedImage.height;
    // inputBuffer = Float32List(pixelCount * 3);
    // const double normalizationFactor = 1.0 / 255.0;
    // for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
    //   final pixel = resizedImage[i];
    //   inputBuffer[i * 3] = ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF) * normalizationFactor; // Red
    //   inputBuffer[i * 3 + 1] = ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF) * normalizationFactor; // Green
    //   inputBuffer[i * 3 + 2] = (pixel & 0xFF) * normalizationFactor; // Blue
    // }

    final pixels = resizedImage.getBytes(format: image_lib.Format.rgb);
    inputBuffer = Float32List.fromList(pixels.map((pixel) => pixel / 255.0).toList());
    inputBuffer = inputBuffer.reshape([1 , 256 , 256 , 3 ]) ;
    inputs = [inputBuffer];
    // print("️ Image resized and normalized Mediapipe: $inputBuffer");
  }
}

This is the code the input buffer is of type [1 , 256 , 256 , 3] and the image utils is doing the basic preprocessing like converting the cameraImage into image . the point of the image should be normalized [0 , 1] . But this image preprocessing is just taking around 70ms . Can anyone help me out ?
